# How to add a location proximity alert that triggers only using GPS_PROVIDER as provider and not using NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, gps, android-intent, location, proximity

I am able to set a location proximity alert with addProximityAlert and receive the alerts with a broadcast receiver.

But how will I be able to identify the location proximity alert is fired from a location provided by a GPS_PROVIDER and not a NETWORK_PROVIDER. I just want to make sure that the alerts are fired from an accurate location.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider()

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the opposite problem - I would not want it to use the GPS provider due to the battery drain. But it seems there is no currently known solution. One thing I might be investigating is setting the location radius higher - hoping that a radius of 1000m would automatically not use GPS for example. In my current testing, it seems a radius of 250m will definitely trigger GPS location. At leas

Answer (score 0):

I read on various sources that ProximityAlerts use BOTH Network and GPS provider, so I think that it really depends on the specified radius.
In my test, if I have GPS enabled but set a 1000m radius, it fires the alert in a way that makes me think it's using the Network provider, because I'm sure I'm over the 1000 radius (thus the position detected by the device could only be approximated)

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use GPS provider as it ideals when phone's screen is off, and battery drain issues, but still if you want to then use following:

```
LocationListener ll;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, -1, proximityIntent);
//you have to define latitude,longitude,radius etc parameters yourself
```

you can change "GPS_PROVIDER" to "NETWORK_PROVIDER" in order to use network provided location